# Powershell Combining variable expressions on a single command line

Tags: powershell, variables, escaping, interpolation

I'm trying to understand how Powershell processes variable expressions on a command line (as a parameter to a cmdlet, for instance).  I can't seem to understand exactly how it parses expressions involving multiple variables (and/or properties on variables).  Here are some example based on the following predefined variables:

```
$a = 'abc'
$b = 'def'
$f = Get-ChildItem .\Test.txt   # assuming such a file exists in the current directory
```

Example 1:

```
echo $a$b
```

Output: `abcdef`

Example 2:

```
echo $a\$b
```

Output: `abc\def`

Example 3:

```
echo $f.BaseName
```

Output: `Test`

Example 4:

```
echo $a\$f.BaseName
```

Output: `abc\C:\Test.txt.BaseName`

Basically, I don't understand why I can combine two variables (examples 1 and 2), and I can use variable properties (example 3), but I can't combine variables with other variable properties (example 4).  I've tried various escape sequences (using the backtick) to no avail.

I realize I can accomplish this using `$()` style expressions, like:

```
echo $($a + '\' + $f.BaseName)
```

I just don't understand why the other form (example 4) is invalid--it reads cleaner in my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr:**

The ***safest* option is to always *use explicit double-quoting* for *compound* arguments**, so that the **usual [*string expansion* (interpolation) rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) apply**.

Applied to your examples (I'm using `Write-Output`, because that's what `echo` is an alias for in PowerShell):

```
Write-Output "$a$b" # example 1
Write-Output "$a\$b" # example 2
Write-Output "$a\$($f.BaseName)" # example 4 - note the required $(...)
```

The only exception is example 3, because there you're not dealing with a *compound* argument, but rather a *single expression*:

```
Write-Output $f.BaseName # example 3: OK without quoting
Write-Output "$($f.BaseName)" # equivalent with double-quoting
```

---

**PowerShell *mostly* treats compound arguments *as if they were* double-quoted (i.e., expandable) strings, but there are ultimately *too many exceptions* for this behavior to be useful**.

[This GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6467) summarizes all the surprising behaviors.

---

As for **your specific questions**:

> I can't combine variables with other variable properties (example 4).

Actually, `echo $a\$f.BaseName` is a case where the compound token *is* implicitly treated as if it were enclosed in `"..."`, and it is precisely because of that that you need to enclose `$f.BaseName` in `$(...)`, because that's what [the string-expansion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) require.

```
echo $a\$($f.BaseName)
```

> I realize I can accomplish this using `$()` style expressions, like:
>   `echo $($a + '\' + $f.BaseName)`

Actually, it's better and more efficient to simply use `(...)` in this case, because what you want to evaluate is a *single expression*:

```
echo ($a + '\' + $f.BaseName)
```

[briantist's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3905079/briantist) has more on the difference between `(...)` (single-statement only) and `$(...)` (multiple statements, with pipeline logic).

Comment: So is it better to use the double-quoted approach or `($a + '\' + $f.BaseName)`?

Comment: @glancep: I'd say that's a matter of taste, though `(...)` is technically probably more efficient (that will rarely matter in real life, though). However, if your expression must evaluate to something other than a _string_, use  of `(...)` is a must.

Comment: @glancep: To pick up on EBGreen's tip, though: your specific example is more robustly written as `(Join-Path $a $f.BaseName)` - note how it is another _command_ that's nested inside `(...)`

Answer (score 2):

There are some subtle differences between `$()` and `()`. I would say that in your example, and in most, you should use `()`.

`$()` can be used when you need something more complex, or expressions that don't work in `()`. Note that the output of `$()` is basically like the output a pipeline, so some things you might not expect will happen. For example look at the output of these two:

```
(1..10 -as [string[]]).GetType()
$(1..10 -as [string[]]).GetType()
```

In the second case, the `[string[]]` array was unrolled and then re-grouped as PowerShell's default array output type of `[object[]]`.

[See this GitHub issue for more information about the vagaries of how arguments are treated and parsed when unquoted and ungrouped](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3217).